# Wireless settings are not available to me despite installing its driver in ubuntu!

Tags: wireless, dkms

I was enabled broadcam drivers from software & update in linux but now i don't have any setting for connecting wireless. As i tried to reinstall its driver, i face an error during the intsalling:

```
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-32-generic

Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-32-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-32-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tested most of the solutions around the internet but its problem doesn't solved!

Comment: Are you using 20.04 or 20.10?

Comment: 20.04 (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal do

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
```

Reboot

The bcmwl-kernel-source package in 20.04 repos is not patched for the 5.8 kernels yet

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and help in solving my problem (: